# How to create strings with length between two numbers in one field and id in other

Tags: postgresql

I need to create many strings which have format: `id | string` (each new string should be different length between 3 and 8 symbols)

I wrote this:

```
SELECT id, array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT chr((97 + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) FROM generate_series(1, floor(random() * (8 - 3 + 1) + 3)::integer)), '') str FROM generate_series(1, 10) id;
```

but each of string has different `id` and has a same `string`

I expect:

```
id    str 
1     sdfg
2     ghfdrr
3     ugh
```

but I have:

```
id    str 
1     sdfg
2     sdfg
3     sdfg
```

Comment: `(SELECT chr((97 + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) FROM ...` is a subquery; it is evaluated once and its result is used in each result from the "outer" generate_series results. That's why you're getting the same string each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
select id,array_to_string(array_agg(chr((97 + round(random() * 25)) :: integer)),'') str 
from (
select id,generate_series(1,strlen) from (
  select generate_series(1,10) id,floor(random() * (8 - 3 + 1) + 3)::integer strlen
 ) a
 ) b group by id order by id
```